# Credit Card Error. What doe "Bad Track 2" mean?

Tags: credit-card, authorization

I am receiving this error when a customer is trying a transaction.
What causes it?

Comment: This isn't a security question. Contact your card provider or equipment manufacturer. In any case, I'd guess it means precisely what it says - track 2 of the card data is damaged.

Comment: Axle welcome to [security.se]. Please take a few moments to review the [FAQ], and also [ask] - you've already asked several poor questions that are not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that the magnetic stripe on the card is unreadable, or the reader itself is broken or gummed up. There are 2 tracks on the magnetic stripe on a credit card, track 2 in this case is damaged or perhaps simply covered with some sort of dirt or dust. Try cleaning the card and/or the reader.

From a security perspective it could be that this credit card is counterfeit, that it was done badly, however there's no way you can really tell. More likely it's just a bad card.